# Internet from Wi-Fi on Kubuntu 21.10 doesn't work after moving from 1st to 2nd room

Tags: wireless, kubuntu, internet, 21.10

I am a Thinkpad T420 owner and have Kubuntu 21.10 on my laptop.

I am struggling with an annoying problem, namely when I move from 1 to 2 rooms, the Wi-Fi internet stops working.
Sometimes restarting a few times will help, but not always.

I had a similar problem with Wi-Fi on Arch Linux, I also referred to the help forum with this problem, but I did not receive a permanent solution to the problem, so I gave up on Arch.

As before I had (K)Ubuntu, such problems did not occur. I hope my network card has not been damaged.
I will just emphasize that the internet always works via Ethernet, but I do not always have the option of using Ethernet.

My wireless interface is `Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak]`.

Has anyone had a similar problem?

How can I prevent this problem from recurring?

Regards

Comment: Hello. The issue is with the physical WiFi card and or wireless router. You yourself have said it has been an issue before. Nothing in this question points to any issue with the OS.

Comment: The enemies of WiFi are distance and interference (physical and electromagnetic) If you're only having problems as you move between rooms, that indicates that the problem is with the physical location of your device in relation to the router and other objects like walls or electronic devices. There's really nothing you can do about this with software or your OS and doesn't implicate a problem with the OS.

Comment: I would like to add that before I turn off the computer, I save the VM state to VirtualBox so as not to lose progress. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: That seems highly unlikely.  The only variable you indicated is that the problem happens when you change location, so the problem is probably the change in location. Ockham's Razor!  But if you have a hypothesis, test it!

Comment: Have you tried changing the orientation of the antennas on the router?

Answer (score 0):

What @Nmath says is the basics: "The enemies of WiFi are distance and interference (physical and electromagnetic)"

I suggest that you use your Smartphone to analyze signal levels (strength!),
e.g. install any of these https://play.google.com/store/search?q=wifi%20analyzer and try
*(I personally use the "[farproc](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=farproc)" app, finding it convenient)*

Note that a difference of ONE meter in position may make or break your connection possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Nmath said. Metal doors, bearing walls (reinforced with metal ) influence the wifi-signal. Solution can be wifi signal repeaters or using your powerlines for ethernet signal (like so: https://www.hns-berks.co.uk/blogs/power-line-adapters-pros-and-cons).